# SFTP to S3 code working locally, but not on Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sftp

I have some small four function Lambda, which aims to transfer files from SFTP to an S3 bucket.

If I trigger the code locally, then it runs to completion and file is transferred from SFTP to S3, repeatedly.

If I upload the code to Lambda, and trigger using the test event, the code execute but unfortunately in general, no file is transferred. I do not receive any errors. But I don't get the console.logs from within the s3.upload(), so I assume means it's some sort of execution time-out issue? How do I ensure that all the async await code executes before the Lambda terminates? (It did however work once, but I've been unable to repeat it!)

```js
const Client = require("ssh2-sftp-client");
const sftpConfig = require("./config/sftp");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const sftpDir = "/mysftp/source/directory";
const bucketName = 'myTargetS3Bucket';

function timestampLessThanADayOld(timestampMilliseconds) {
  const currentTimestampMilliseconds = Date.now();
  const timeDifferenceMilliseconds =
    currentTimestampMilliseconds - timestampMilliseconds;
  return timeDifferenceMilliseconds < 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}

const transferFile = async (file, sftp, bucketName) => {
  try {
    const sftpFilePath = `${sftpDir}/${file.name}`;
    console.log(`Attempting to transfer ${file.name}`);
    const fileData = await sftp.get(sftpFilePath);
    const s3Key = `Uploads/${file.name}`;
    const s3Params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: s3Key,
      Body: fileData,
    };
    await s3.upload(s3Params, (err, data) => {
      console.log("data: ",data);
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error: ", err);
      } else {
        console.log(`Upload succeeded: ${data.Location}`);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error reading file: ", error);
  }
};

const copyNewFiles = async () => {
  console.log("Transfer initiated");
  const sftp = new Client();
  try {
    await sftp.connect(sftpConfig);
    const files = await sftp.list(sftpDir);
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (timestampLessThanADayOld(files[i].modifyTime)) {
        await transferFile(files[i], sftp, bucketName);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to SFTP:", error);
  } finally {
    sftp.end();
  }
  console.log("Transfer complete");
};

module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    await copyNewFiles();
}

// if executing locally, I add a `copyNewFiles();` here to trigger it, 
// and run it using `node sftpTransfer.js`
```

From CloudWatch here's the rough output of the event log:

```
2024-01-02T19:10:49.464+00:00   INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:14.v42 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1::runtime:xxxxxx

2024-01-02T19:10:50.234+00:00   START RequestId: 9eb64b6a-xxxxxx Version: $LATEST

2024-01-02T19:10:50.238+00:00   2024-01-02T19:10:50.238Z 9eb64b6a-xxxxxx INFO Transfer initiated

2024-01-02T19:10:53.319+00:00   2024-01-02T19:10:53.319Z 9eb64b6a-xxxxxx INFO Attempting to transfer MyFile.txt

2024-01-02T19:10:54.175+00:00   2024-01-02T19:10:54.175Z 9eb64b6a-xxxxxx INFO Transfer complete

2024-01-02T19:10:54.180+00:00   END RequestId: 9eb64b6a-xxxxxx

2024-01-02T19:10:54.180+00:00   REPORT RequestId: 9eb64b6a-xxxxxx Duration: 3944.60 ms Billed Duration: 3945 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 89 MB Init Duration: 769.30 ms
```

Comment: By default Lambda times out after 3 seconds - what if you increase this timeout?  It looks like you're at about 4 seconds.

Comment: You might want to add some additional `console.log()` lines to determine where it got up to -- such as after the `sftp.get()`.

Comment: You're not using the SDK v2 promise interface. Use `const rc = await s3.upload(s3Params).promise();` As an aside, you should probably be writing new apps with the v3 SDK, rather than v2.

Comment: **Side-note:** If your goal is to send files from S3 to an external SFTP server, or retrieve files from an external SFTP server and store them in S3, you can [Transfer files by using an SFTP connector - AWS Transfer Family](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/transfer-sftp-connectors.html). Here's a presentation on the topic: [AWS Transfer Family: SFTP connectors | Amazon Web Services - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm-FMGrVpAg)